# Scala: How to implement Custom Enumerations

Tags: scala

Here below is my custom `Enumeration`...

```
object DocState extends Enumeration { thisenum =>

  type DocState = State

  val New = Value("new", new FromNew)
  val Open = Value("open", new FromOpen)

  class State(name: String, convertWith: Transduction) extends Val(name) {

    def apply(message: Save) = convertWith(message)
    def apply(message: Edit) = convertWith(message)
  }

  protected final def Value(
    name: String, convertWith: Transduction
  ) = new State(name, convertWith)

  sealed trait Message
  case class Save(text: String) extends Message
  case class Edit(text: String) extends Message

  def apply(name: String) = thisenum.withName(name).asInstanceOf[State]
}

trait Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save)
  def apply(message: Edit)
}

class FromNew extends Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save): DocState = { ... }
  def apply(message: Edit): DocState = { ... }
}

class FromOpen extends Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save): DocState = { ... }
  def apply(message: Edit): DocState = { ... }
}
```

... and it works like this:

```
import DocState._

val currentState = New(Save("hello")) // currentState is New
val newState = currentState(Edit("hello")) // newState is Open
```

The code above works fine... but `New` and `Open` are instances of `State`, not instances of `DocState`, and this is a problem when an `Enumeration` is required like in the example here below:

```
trait DocException[S <: Enumeration] extends ServiceException {

  val state: Option[S]
}

object DocException {

  def apply[S <: Enumeration](message: String, _state: Option[S]) = new RuntimeException(message) with DocException[S] {
    val state: Option[S] = _state
  }
}
```

The following code does not compile:

```
val e = DocException("state error", Some(New))
```

I always get the following error message:

```
inferred type arguments [test.DocState.DocState] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [S <: Enumeration]
[error] val e = DocException("state error", Some(New))

/home/j3d/Projects/test/app/DocFsm.scala:71: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Some[test.DocState.DocState]
[error]  required: Option[S]
[error]             val e = DocException("state error", Some(New))
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to implement my custom `Enumeration`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but `Enumeration` has some issues that makes it unsafe, and it also looks like you are using it in a very unusual way. Its better to use the sealed class with case classes/objects pattern, like you do with `Message`.

Comment: I use an Enumeration to create a finite state machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to get the right implementation for my state machine:

```
object DocState extends Enumeration { thisenum =>

  type DocState = Value

  val New = Value("new", new FromNew)
  val Open = Value("open", new FromOpen)

  class Val(name: String, convertWith: Transduction) extends super.Val(name) {

    def !(message: Save) = convertWith(message)
    def !(message: Edit) = convertWith(message)
  }

  private def Value(name: String, convertWith: Transduction) = new Val(name, convertWith)

  sealed trait Message
  case class Save(text: String) extends Message
  case class Edit(text: String) extends Message

  def apply(name: String) = thisenum.withName(name).asInstanceOf[Val]

  implicit def toVal(value: Value) = value.asInstanceOf[Val]
  implicit def toString(state: DocState) = state.toString
}

trait Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save)
  def apply(message: Edit)
}

class FromNew extends Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save): DocState = { ... }
  def apply(message: Edit): DocState = { ... }
}

class FromOpen extends Transduction {

  def apply(message: Save): DocState = { ... }
  def apply(message: Edit): DocState = { ... }
}
```

Here below is an example of how to use the state machine:

```
import DocState._

// initialize the state machine
val state1 = DocState("new")              // state1 is New

// send an edit message to state1
val state2 = state1 ! Edit("my comment")  // state2 is Edit
```

I hope that helps.